# Developer story UI bugs

Tags: bug, developer-story

1. When I go to my developer story, I see the following for all of my
   'items' (note this is the default state):

   [image]

   If I press cancel on all of them, it looks nice again. But after
   reloading the page the bugs are back.
2. The buttons on this form seem a bit off
   [image]

Browser is Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: add((add(add))add) eh?

Comment: That Add button reminds me of [this](https://youtu.be/VwWqFRsOcaY).

Comment: Can't repro on Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. Maybe it was hotfixed and you got the issues on the bad build?

Comment: I'm going to click your `add` button... on the `add` button!

Comment: @Filnor I checked right after you posted and the bugs were still there, but I just checked again and it seems to be fixed now

Comment: recursion........